# Как убрать белый фон с картинки?

Tags: python, pygame, png

Что получается = https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp4ZM.png

Картинка = https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/volleyball_3231041
Что нужно исправить в этом коде, чтобы убрать белый фон с картинки?.Set_colorkey не убирает белый фон, он остаётся на картинке.

```
import pygame

MAX_X = 1280
MAX_Y = 720

GREEN = (0,250,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (250,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

img = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Картинки\volleyball.png")
speed = 3

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = img
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)!!!
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (MAX_X / 2, MAX_Y / 2)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += speed    
        if self.rect.left > MAX_X:
            self.rect.right = 0




fps = 60
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((MAX_X,MAX_Y))
pygame.display.set_caption('PyGame!')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


    clock.tick(fps)
    all_sprites.update()
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду `убрать белый фон` - внутри мяча или где?

Comment: покажите изображение экрана, которое у вас получается.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp4ZM.png.Убрать белый фон за мячом

Answer (score 1):

вы как-то не правильно сохранили картинку.

```
import pygame

MAX_X = 1280
MAX_Y = 720

GREEN = (0,250,0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED = (250,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)

img = pygame.image.load("volleyball.png")                       # !!!
speed = 3

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = img
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)                        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (MAX_X / 2, MAX_Y / 2)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += speed    
        if self.rect.left > MAX_X:
            self.rect.right = 0



fps = 60
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((MAX_X,MAX_Y))
pygame.display.set_caption('PyGame!')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)


while True:
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


    clock.tick(fps)
    all_sprites.update()
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема была не в файле, а в размере картинки.Я заходил в paint, чтобы уменьшить картинку, из-за этого могли происходить неполадки.

Comment: @Ярослав я сомневаюсь в том, что вы прокомментировали - размер тут не при чем. Мой ответ помог вам решить проблему?

Comment: Нет не помог,но всё равно спасибо! Я скачал стандартный размер и всё работает.Путь к картинке точно такой же r"C:\Картинки\volleyball.png" .

Comment: @Ярослав вы читали мой ответ: `'вы как-то не правильно сохранили картинку'` ?.